# Download google app engine entities as CSV

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

In our GAE app, users often need to download entities of a particular type as CSV.  New entities are frequently being added/updated which makes it infeasible to write all entities to a blob in advance or at fixed intervals.

For around 50000 entities (each entity < 2 KB) fetched in batches of 500 it takes over 2 minutes to write to a CSV file blob and costs nearly $1.  Also users have to wait for a long time to receive a file which is usually only a few (< 5) MBs.

I have 2 questions:

A) Can the time to write the blob possibly be reduced by configuring a map-reduce pipeline for the export?

B) Is there a way to reduce the cost of fetching large number of entities from the datastore and writing to blobs?

Edit:  Just learned that mapreduce can only run on all entities of a kind, not a filtered subset.  So mapreduce will probably increase the cost by a whole lot.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

1. You should use A[ppEngine pipeline](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/) it can improve the speed because it will distributed the job across several instances.
2. You can reduce the cost of fetching entities by using projection queries in which you specify  which attributes you want to fetch.
3. As for the download speed, are you using the blobstore with BlobstoreDownloadHandler?

Comment: Shay, thanks.  What if we need to always fetch all the properties of each entity?  Any cost reduction strategy there?

Comment: @Yasser It will sound ugly but you can store the csv line as an attribute of the entity and update it when ever the entity is created/updated. fetch only the line when retrieving the entity I think it should cost less then retrieving all the attributes.

Comment: Shay, a complicating factor to your "store the line" suggestion is that projection queries aren't supported for unindexed attributes.  So Yasser would need to be careful to stay under the limits of str (500 chars), and pay the extra write costs associated with another indexed property.

Comment: Yes i am using the blobstore dl handler but the actual download is not the bottleneck.. Its creating a blob from datastore entries thats problematic

Comment: Oh and jeffrey  is right, there is no way i can stay under the 500 chars limit.  My average entity size is around 2KB raw.

Comment: Gentlemen, i updated the question.  Looks like mapreduce will increase the costs by a whole lot because it doesnt let you filter entities yet.  Cant afford to run a job on millions of entities and export only a few hundred K.  Any comments?